# Class not working in link

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to change the colour of my link in my webpage, the css code is below.

```
    <style>
     .company_link A:link { 
     color: #dd3333;
     text-decoration: none;
     }
     .company-link A:hover {
     color: #F6CA4C;
     text-decoration: underline;
     }
    .company-link A:visited {
    color: #F6CA4C;
    text-decoration: none;
     }
   .company-link A:active {
   color: yellow;
   text-decoration: none;
    }
  </style>
```

And here is the link.

```
 <?php echo "<a class=\"company-link\" href=\"company.php?ip={$ip}&id={$id}\">$company_name_live</a>";?><br><span style="color:#dd3333;"><?php echo $row['multivisit']; ?></span>
```

I have tried putting the class in different places, using single quotes and even attaching the class to the table row, but i just can't seem to change the colour of the link.

Comment: `company_link`...`company-link` maybe you could change that

Comment: Thanks, I that was a silly mistake, but didn't make a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
<?php echo "<a class=\"company_link\" href=\"company.php?ip=".$ip."&id=".$id."\">$company_name_live</a>";?><br><span style="color:#dd3333;"><?php echo $row['multivisit']; ?></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Now you're selecting a *child* `a` of the class `.company-link`, but it's the `a` which HAS the class `.company-link`. Should be:

```
a.company-link:hover{}
```

and so on.

*Edit after comment:*

Don't mean to sound arrogant, but this is the solution for the code you posted. So either your code is different, or you have something else that overrides this rule, something else later on in your css?

Comment: Thanks Didn't change anything

Comment: this is the right answer..taking into consideration the class given to the <a> tag inline..

Comment: I have posted the code above, all that is left out id the table frame.

Answer (score 0):

```
  a.company_link:link{}
```

Try this

Comment: Copy paste the html and style on jsfiddle plz. Or give the link to live or dev site

Answer (score 0):

When you want to style elements with classes, you have to use the following syntax:

```
element.class { }
```

or, in your situation:

```
a.company { }
```

You can see what I mean in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barbu110/kzjcm/) that will certainly sole your problem. You can just copy the styling into your file.

The syntax:

```
.company a { }
```

is used for all the `a` elements inside a `.company` container, for example:

```
<div class="company">
    <a href="#">Styled link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Styled link 2</a>
</div>
```

The above example will style all the `a` childs of a `.company` class element. You can check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/barbu110/kzjcm/1/).